# ajax jquery: the return value is always undefind

Tags: jquery, ajax

I followed the debugger and I am receiving data from my server but the objData variable is always undefined when pass the data from the GetAjax function to the GetPlacesAroundMe.

As you can see I set the ajax to be sync.

*The code is added below

Thanks, I will appreciate any help.

```
Model.prototype.AjaxGet = function(sUrl,sData,sType){
     var result="";
    $.ajax({
           url: sUrl+"?"+sData,
           type: sType,
           async: false,
           success: function(data){

              return (data);

           },
           error:function(exception){
           alert(exception.responseText);
           }
    });
    //return result;
}

 Model.prototype.GetPlacesAroundMe = function(data){


    var objData = this.AjaxGet(ip_address+"/purpleserver/index.php/selectController/GetPlacesAroundMe",data,"get");

     return objData;

}
```

Comment: because $.ajax is asynchron

Comment: pass another parameter called callback and return it in your success/error functions

Comment: kishore- I tried it and it didn't work.
And i set sync to false, meaning it is async, am I right?

Comment: @Kishore you can't return anything from the callback. that isn't supported.

Comment: James- I don't think, it is a duplicate, the different is that I have 3 functions:
foo()- who calls GetPlacesAroundMe()- which calls AjaxGet.
data received in the foo function is undefined- this is my problem.

Comment: kishore- is their any workaround? which i can use?

Comment: @Roy Working with async functions, you have two options: callbacks or jquery `deferred` objects. Adding more functions doesn't change that, just the complexity. You could pass a callback from the front all the way to `AjaxGet` or pass a `promise` from `AjaxGet` all the way to the front. It's up to you.

Comment: @KevinB he can pass another argument in the AjaxGet function called callback and in the success function Roy can just do this right callback(data); why wont this work?

Comment: That will work just fine. I was referring to this: *"pass another parameter called callback and **return** it in your success/error functions"* you can't return it, but you can execute it.

Comment: I can do the trick of passing callback, and it's work but I can't return it. :(